# access_denied while logging into asp.net MVC 5 website using facebook Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, facebook-login

I want to login to my ASP.NET MVC app using facebook, and getting an access denied error. Here is what I have done:

I have created an App on: developer.facebook.com, this is the basic settings:
[image]

I have not changed anything on Advanced, settings.

This is the Facebook Login -> settings (under product)
[image]

My application is default ASP.Net MVC 5 website, I have uncommented the facebook authentication section in Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
           appSecret: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"]);
```

When I go to the login page, it redirects me to facebook login page:

[image]

And then I am redirected back to the login page... no user is registered in the database... I know my DB registration is working because users can login with the same process using google...

I am getting access_denied in facebook response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not installed: **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook** Nuget Package, it works now, after I installed the package.